# HashSet<String> .contains()

Tags: java, collections, hashset

I'm having issues using .contains to check if a String is stored in a HashSet.

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Controller
{
    private Queue<String> queue;
    private HashSet<String> blocked;

    public Controller()
    {
        queue = new Queue<String>();
        blocked = new HashSet<String>();
    }

    public void add(String item)
    {        
        if (!(blocked.contains(item))) queue.add(item);
    }
}
```

I've had a look around and understand that I need to override the .equals method. Does this mean that I'd have to make a new class that extends HashSet and then declare an instance of that new class in place of 'HashSet blocked;'?

I'm aware of the reason that simply using == to compare two Strings doesn't work, but I'm confused because the code below does seem to work in some cases but not all.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Regards

Comment: That code should work; `String` does override `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Comment: What cases does it not work? Remember case sensitivity.

Comment: I fear you misunderstand. If you are using an object in a `HashSet`, that object should have good `hashCode` and `equals` methods, not the `HashSet` itself. Since `String` comes with it's own `equals` and `hashCode` methods, there should be no extra work to do on your part. What do you expect that code to do and why "doesn't it work"?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I say it doesn't work as Strings that are in the 'block' HashSet are still being added to the queue. I've tried printing to the console to check and it's definitely happening. It's certainly nothing to do with case. Could it be that there are characters that I can't see when printing to the console are contained within the String?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to override the `equals` method - the `String` already has a very good pair of `hashCode/equals` that are efficient in terms of CPU cycles and in terms of distributing different strings to different hash buckets.

A pair of `hashCode/equals` methods is required for items placed in a hash set in order to enable the correct work of the container: `hashCode` decides on the hash "bucket" in which the object is placed, and `equals` resolves collisions among non-equal objects with identical hash codes.

Wikipedia has an illustrated [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) on hash tables. Read through it to improve your understanding of the `hashCode/equals` concepts, they are fundamental to using unsorted associative containers in any language, including Java.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I say it doesn't work as Strings that are in the 'block' HashSet are still being added to the queue. I've tried printing to the console to check and it's definitely happening. It's certainly nothing to do with case.

Could it be that there are characters that I can't see when printing to the console are contained within the String?

Comment: @stasis When printing to the console, consider adding "guard characters" around your words -- say, single quotes or square brackets. This way you would be able to tell if one word has trailing spaces while the other does not. I assume that your code is not multithreaded, right?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I came to the conclusion that I needed to override the equals method by having a browse around and thought this would be a similar problem. Going on the fact that I shouldn't have to override .equals to make .contains work, why do you think it would be that .contains isn't working for me in this case? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Yes I've got containers around it to check, there are no whitespace characters. It's not multithreaded at the moment but I do plan to make it so

Comment: @stasis Whatever does not work in your code is broken for reasons unrelated to String's hashCode/equals. For example, an item may be added to `blocked` *after* it has been added to the `queue`.

Comment: That makes much more sense! I'll have a mess around with the code now, thanks a lot for your help